# Is it necessary to set a stage as an input processor when creating a touchpad?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I mean, I've been searching it, they always use set a stage as an input processor after they had added the `Touchpad`to the `Stage` because it extends from `Actor` indireclty(it extends from `Widget` that extends from `Actor`), just like this:

```
myStage.addActor(myTouchpad);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(myStage);
```

Is there any other way to set the input processor when creating a touchpad?

Comment: Can I ask why you do not wish to use a stage? If it's because you need to use another `InputProcessor` you can use their [InputMultiplexer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html) to combine two (or more) `InputProcessor`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a class that extends InputProcessor.

Then add add it as the Gdx InputProcessor.

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(MyInputProcessor);
```

More information on the [LibGDX wiki: Event handling](https://libgdx.com/wiki/input/event-handling).

Comment: But then the joystick wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: Make it so that it also extends ControllerListener.